# How to resize for every window?

Tags: html, css, resize, margin

I have made a site, but now there is a problem. It is made in a div(.body) with a margin of 20%, but when the screen gets smaller, it won't resize like it want it to.

This is the code of it. what can i do to make it resize smaller, and if necessary back to zero?

```
    .body {
        width: 60%;
        height: 1200px;
        border: 1px solid white;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        margin-left: 20%;
        position: relative;
        min-width: 1100px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `min-width: 1100px;` so it will not go smaller than that. Perhaps that was a typo and you meant to write `max-width: 1100px;`. That will fix the problem:

```
.body {
    width: 60%;
    height: 1200px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    margin-left: 20%;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1100px;
}
```